# Creating an array of values in FactoryGirl, each of which is unique

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, factory-bot

I have this factory defined:

```
factory :post, :parent => :post_without_countries, class: Post do |p|
       p.country_ids {|country_ids| [country_ids.association(:country), country_ids.association(:country)]} 
end
```

And I'm wanting it to output two unique countries. Instead it just inserts the same country as the association twice:

```
#<Post id: nil, title: "Atque id dolorum consequatur.", body: "Praesentium saepe ullam magnam. Voluptatum tempora ...", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: 1>
[#<Country id: 1, name: "Dominican Republic", isocode: "lyb", created_at: "2012-10-20 13:52:18", updated_at: "2012-10-20 13:52:18">, #<Country id: 1, name: "Dominican Republic", isocode: "lyb", created_at: "2012-10-20 13:52:18", updated_at: "2012-10-20 13:52:18">]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Better use the `build_list` or `create_list` methods:

```
post.countries = create_list(:country, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing:

```
2.times { post.countries << FactoryGirl.create(:country) }
```

in RSpec, you can make an `after_create` hook like this:

```
after_create do |post|
  2.times { post.countries << FactoryGirl.create(:country) }
end
```

If you need to customize the number of times you want to create a country, you can make a transient attribute:

```
#in the post factory definition
ignore do
  num_countries 0 #default to zero
end

#different after_create
after_create do |post, proxy|
  proxy.num_countries.times { post.countries << FactoryGirl.create(:country) }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like factory girl might not be iterating properly.  The two questions that pop into my mind are.

Are you using `FactoryGirl.build` when you meant to use `FactoryGirl.create`?

Have you tried replacing `p.country_ids` with `p.sequence(:country_ids)`

I hope that those point you in the right direction.  If not, perhaps more information?

Comment: thanks for responding, but I'm using the build method as I'm testing a model. I tried to change it but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: I tried changing p.country_ids to:

` p.sequence(:country_ids) {|country_ids| [country_ids.association(:country), country_ids.association(:country)]} `

And I get

` NoMethodError: undefined method `association' for 6:Fixnum `

Comment: I think I should back up and ask what exactly you are trying to do with this factory.  You are trying to associate a number literal with a class, which doesn't work.  What is the purpose of this factory?  How are things supposed to be associated?

Comment: So my model is Posts HABTM Countries.

What I'm trying to do is generate a number of different countries and attach them to my post. At the moment it is generating a *one* country and attaching that to my post, twice. It is ignoring the second item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I fixed this by taking my creation of the many Countries relationship out the factory and just creating it in RSpec instead:

```
  post = FactoryGirl.build(:post)
  2.times { post.countries << FactoryGirl.create(:country) }
```